# Completely Regular space and the topology $\tau_A$

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, separation-axioms

I'm trying the following problem:
Let $\left(X, \tau \right)$ be a completely regular space and $A$  a closed subset of $X$. Show that $\left(X, \tau_A\right)$ is completely regular where $\tau_A=\{U\cup \left(V\cap A\right): U, V \in \tau \}$

So, I did the following:
Let $F$ be a closed subset of $X$ with the new topology. So $X\setminus F$ is an open subset of $X$. Then, $X\setminus F= U\cup (V\cap A)$ for some $U$, $V$ in $\tau$. Let $x \in X\setminus F$. So we have two cases:

If $x\in U$ the result follows easy.
The problem is when $x\in V\cap A$. I suspect that the fact of $A$ being closed is strong in this part but I can't see it.
I tried with $X=\mathbb{R}$ and the usual topology and $[0,1]=A$. Notice that the set $K=(-\infty,0)\cup [\frac{1}{2},1]$ is closed in the new topology. In this point, is easy construct a continuous function such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(K)\subseteq \{1\}$. The new topology, as we can observe, solve some problems in the left limit: $f$ can be defined as the line segment between $(0,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$ as points in the plane and $1$ in other case. This function is continuous. Is a interesting exercise, but I can't solve it in the second case.

Comment: It looks like your new topological space is the [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology)) of $A$ and $X - A$. So, since complete regularity is presumably invariant under disjoint union, you will be done if you show that open subspaces and closed subspaces of completely regular spaces are completely regular.

Comment: @MikeF . All subspaces of a completely regular space are completely regular.

Comment: I can't see how this topology and the disjoint union are the same or the spaces are homeomorphic.

Comment: @UrielHerrera: It should just be a few short steps, starting from the definitions, to show $\tau_A$ and the disjoint union topology coincide. A couple notes: (1) since $A$ is closed, $X-A$ is open.  A subset of $X-A$ is open in $X-A$ if and only if it is open in $X$. (2) Given $U$ open in $X$, you can write it as $(U-A) \cup (U \cap A)$ where $U-A$ is open in $X-A$ and $U \cap A$ is open in $A$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Good point. I agree with that.

Comment: @MikeF Oh. Sorry for that. Some misconception about disjoint union topology... In this point, I have to prove that the disjoint union topology is completely regular, but I suppose that is not a problem. I'll try it. Thank you.

Comment: @MikeF It’s not (homeomorphic to) the disjoint sum topology, it’s a refinement of the original topology by adding the relatively open subsets of $A$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Really? Where does the following stray? An open set for the disjoint sum $(X-A)\sqcup A$ is $U \cup (V \cap A)$ where $U$ is open in $X-A$ and $V$ is open in $X$. But, $U$ is also open in $X$, so $U \cup (V \cap A) \in \tau_A$. Conversely, consider $U \cup (V \cap A) \in \tau_A$ where $U,V \subseteq X$ are open. Since $V \cap A$ is open for the disjoint sum and $U = (U-A) \cup (U \cap A)$ is open for the disjoint sum, we have that $U \cup (V \cap A)$ is open for the disjoint sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation (from Set Theory): For function $h$ and $S\subset dom(h)$ write $h''S =\{h(s):s\in S\}.$ (Read as "$h$-double-prime-$S$".)

Let $p \in X .$ Let $C$ be $\tau_X$-closed with $p\not \in C.$

$(1).$ If $p\not \in A:$ Observe that a $\tau_A$-open-set that is disjoint from $A$ is a $\tau$-open-set, so $p\in (X \backslash A) \backslash C\in \tau,$  and there exists a $\tau$-continuous $f:X\to [0,1]$ with $f(p)=0$ and $\{1\}\supseteq f'' (X \backslash ((X  \backslash A) \backslash C)=f'' (A \cup C)\supseteq f''C.$

Now $\tau_A\supset \tau$ so $f$ is also $\tau_A$-continuous.

$(2).$ If $p\in A:$ Take $V\in \tau$ such that $p\in V\cap A\subset X$ \ $C.$ Let $f:X\to [0,1]$ be $\tau$-continuous with $f(p)=0$ and $f''(X$ \ $V)\subseteq \{1\}. $

Now let $ g(q)=f(q)$ for $q\in A$ and let $g(q)=1$ for $q\in X$ \ $A .$

Prove that $g^{-1}[0,r)$ and $g^{-1}(r,1]$ belong to $\tau_A$ for every $r\in (0,1),$ so that $g$ is $\tau_A$-continuous. We have $g(p)=0$ and $g''C\subseteq \{1\}.$

(3). $\tau$ is a $T_1$ topology and $\tau\subset \tau_A$ so $\tau_A$ is also $T_1.$

Comment: In ($2)$,  for $r\in [0,1)$ we have $g^{-1}[0,r)=X$ \  $A) \cup f^{-1}[0,r)=(X$ \  $A)\cup  (A\cap f^{-1}[0,1))\in \tau_A $.... If $A$ were not $\tau$-closed then  $(X$ \  $A) \not \in \tau$ so $g^{-1}[0,r)$  might not belong to $\tau_A.$

Comment: in your comment, $g^{-1}[0,r)=X\setminus A \cup f^{-1}[0,r)$ Are you sure about the equality??? I was thinking that the idea was calculate the preimage of the set $(r,1]$

Comment: If $g(q)\geq r>0$ then $q\in A$ and $g(q)=f(q)\geq r>0. $ So $g^{-1}[r,1]=A\cap f^{-1}[r,1].$ So ......